# One to one relationship direction

Tags: database, database-design

I have a one to one relationship between the table User and the table Address.

Should I have the address_id into the User table? Or should I have the user_id into the address table? And why?

Answer (score 0):

I would say, it depends on what entity is considered more important in your business logic.

Ask yourself a question: what is more likely to happen - one user will get multiple addresses or one address would get multiple users?

Also, consider alternatives:

- if you are 100% sure the address has no meaning without its user, consider not making a separate table for it
- if you are not sure what is more likely to become the "many" instead of "one" and performance is less important than agility, you can create a separate join table for this relation and put an unique constraint per column to ensure you are getting only one row for any given Address or User